# CSS font-size is being ignored inside jquery-ui tabs

Tags: css, jquery-ui, tabs, font-size

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my font-size changes are being ignored.

I have gone and disabled all ui-widget fontsize changes, I have also played around in the development tools in Chrome and made drastic font-size changes, played around with the use of '!important' as well.

It seems to be affecting spacing in between contents and having absolutely no effect on the actual font-sizes. It is all within a `<section>` tag.

I think posting all the effected styles here would be a bit overwhelming, but let me know if there is not enough information here or if you have need of any more information.

Comment: You really need to post some HTML or CSS otherwise we have nothing to go on!

Comment: Drop it in a jsfiddle and share the link. It won't be overwhelming! :)